# python selenium: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH AFTER adding executable to path

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use python's selenium module. I downloaded the Firefox driver and manually added the driver's executable, `C:\Users\me\Desktop\gecko_driver\geckodriver.exe`, to my system's path. I then restarted my Windows machine but unfortunately, I'm still getting the error message: `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

This is not a duplicate of previous stackoverflow questions because those don't address the issue arising AFTER having added the executable to my path.

Comment: how did you add the path exactly ? did you give `C:\Users\me\Desktop\gecko_driver\geckodriver.exe` or `C:\Users\me\Desktop\gecko_driver\` to the paths list ?

Comment: I gave C:\Users\me\Desktop\gecko_driver\geckodriver.exe

Comment: try to add only the folder path, not the exe, but the other solutions in the answers are pretty useful

Comment: It's working now. Thank you :)